# How do I find all objects owned by a role in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to find all the tables and views in Snowflake that are currently owned by a particular role (not my own). How would I find this information and what level of access would I need to perform this query?

EDIT: Previously, had asked for tables and views owned by a *user*, rather than a *role*.

Comment: Objects in Snowflake are owned by a role, not by a user.  Not sure if that helps you go in the right direction or not, but you'd need to start by finding all the roles that the user is in.  You'd likely need accountadmin access or have the Snowflake/account_usage data granted to your role in order to properly query for everything you're looking for.

Comment: I see. Do you know what I would do if I do have admin access? @MikeWalton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of following queries should do the job:

```
show grants to role <role_name>;

SELECT * FROM table(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))
WHERE "privilege" = 'OWNERSHIP'
and "granted_on" in ('TABLE', 'VIEW') ;
```

Comment: Perfect! I don't need admin access, and I get everything I need.

Comment: Please be cautious with this answer, however.  The `show grants` command has a limit of 10k records returned.  So, if you have more data than that....you'd need account_usage to get everything.